# Mergesort algorithm with Θ(n^2 log n) complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, complexity-theory, mergesort

What would cause a mergesort algorithm to have `Θ(n^2 log n)` complexity?

Comment: An extra factor of n. :)

Comment: Merge sort has time complexity =Theta(n*log(n))

Comment: yes but i have to know what kind of a problem can cause this time complexity

Comment: Man if you don't post the code how can we answer?

Comment: you can add a linear search which its complexity is O(n) at each elements swapping to have the complexity O ( n ^ 2 log n) because the complexity of merge sort is O ( n log n )  so if we repeat the linear search n log n time we will have a running time with the complexity that you want to have

Comment: @kabab That's not how asymptotic arithmetics work. [`T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^2` is in `O(n^2)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+2T%28n%2F2%29+%2B+n%5E2)

Comment: @amit the propriety that you have mention is about addition, I m talking about multiplication, i give you and example
for(i = 0; i < m; i++) { do_somthing()} for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { do_somthing()}
the complexity of this program will be O(max(n,m))
but the complexity of this program 
for(i=0; i < m; i++) {for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {do_somethin()}}
is O(n * m)

Comment: @kabab This is not addiotn, this is the new complexity recursive function for mergesort where each steps takes `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)`., and then you invoke recursively on the two smaller subarrays.

Comment: But i asked for theta not o

Comment: @kabab This is similar to the fact that `for (int i = 1; i < n; i*= 2) for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) foo()` is **NOT** `Θ(nlogn)`.

Answer (score 2):

Getting to break mergesort to run in `Θ(n^2logn)` is not as simple as the intuition says, the first thing you'd try to do is to "break" merge and make it run in `Θ(n^2)` instead of `Θ(n)` it can be done by merging the two lists to a new list, which is a linked - list, without remembering the end of the list, so each insertion is `Θ(n)` - what makes each merge step run in `Θ(n^2)`.

**But that's not enough**

It will give us the recursive complexity formula:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^2
```

[But this formula is in `Θ(n^2)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%20%3D%202T%28n%2F2%29%20%2B%20n%5E2), so it's not enough.

Let's reverse engineer it.

To get `Θ(n^2 logn)`, we want to use the [master theorem case 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2), we already have `c=2`, and we need `log_b(a)=2`.

To "make it work", we can set `b=4,a=2`.

This means, the merge sort splits the array into two halves, but "accidently" recursively invokes itself on each half twice.

Now we get the complexity function

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^2
```

And the above is in `Θ(n^2 logn)`, from master theorem case 2.

---

**To summarize:**

To make mergesort run in `Θ(n^2 logn)`, you need:

1. "Break" merge to run in `Θ(n^2 )` (by merging into an unoptimised linked list, for example)
2. Recurse on each half twice.

Comment: i found an easier solution to this problem and it is also from you. Thanks for your help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449447/string-sorting-using-merge-sort